# JSON date to asp.net DateTime is changed at runtime

Tags: asp.net, json, datetime, culture

I've searched around and I'm really not sure why this happens.

Most of the time my app runs in GMT from devices using GMT, but I just span a server up in Singapore, so the time is 8hrs ahead. I'm seeing some strange behaviour with DateTime objects parsed from JSON:

My app received a JSON (ISO 8601) date like this:

> LastSync=2013-01-10T11:05:38.822Z

I'm using a simple .asmx web-service, that uses the built in JSON serializer for .Net 3.5, the automatically parsed DateTime object returns a date 8hrs ahead of what the JSON says it should be. Here's the function:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
 Public Function SyncFlatTable(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal LastSync As DateTime)
    Return WebServiceJSON.SyncFlatTable(tableName, LastSync)
End Function
```

As you can see the LastSync as DateTime argument's value is 8hrs ahead:

[image: LastSync screenshot]
The weird thing is if I return Now(), the JSON output from the web service is:

> newLastSend=/Date(1357817197087)/

Which using a timestamp to date online converter is no-longer 8hrs ahead.

Is this IIS's fault? I can't see any other culture settings everything else is neutral, why would it change the date? How do I stop it, or do I have to take what I'm given and adjust the date to an invariant culture date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that calling .toJSON on any date object, when it's converted to a string representation it is done so using a local date. I needed to adjust this to UTC so that when it's converted it does so with what the date should be for the server:

```
function removeDateUTCOffSetForServer(obj) {
if (obj) {
    for (prop in obj) {
        if (obj[prop] instanceof Date) {
            var d = obj[prop];
            var utc = new Date(d.getTime() - (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
            obj[prop] = utc;
        }
    }
}
return obj;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem as well, I ended up using the sting type to pass in/out the date info.